# Firebase update array value or create new one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I'm trying to update array in firebase. 
I know that I can add new array like this :

```
let array1 : [String] = ["w9pRe7sTj5aUPf3og4vUZ3kVpXs2"]
firebaseRef.child(playerID).child("friends").setValue(array1)
```

but if the user already have an array of "friends", its override the old data with the new.

How I can create new array only if the user have no array of "friends"
if the array is exist just "append" new value.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the structure of your firebase db?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 added screenshot

Comment: have you tried using `updateChildValues` ?

Comment: can you replace this screen shot with a screenshot with expanding these child nodes with keys

Comment: @3stud1ant3 done

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to "append" new value into the array without override exist array with new one.

Please check this example:

```
firebaseRef.child(playerID).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    // check if friends array exist
    if let friendsArr = snapshot.value as? NSArray{
        // add new friend ID to the array
        let newArr = friendsArr.adding("YOUR NEW FRIEND ID")
        // update in firebase DB
        snapshot.ref.setValue(newArr)
    }else{ // No array exist, save new array
        firebaseRef.child(playerID).child("friends").setValue(array1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take here.

**Option 1:** 
Convert the current array into mutable array, add objects to it and set the value again

```
NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firebaseArray];
[mutableArray addObject:@"random_id"];
firebaseRef.child(playerID).child("friends").setValue([mutableArray copy]);
```

Note: This might call the observer's childAdded: method for pre-existing id's as well.

**Option 2:** Convert your array to set. This is the preferred approach in your case, since you don't want multiple similar strings in your "friends" list. Also it will be easy to maintain.

```
firebaseRef.child(playerID).child("friends").child("random_id").setValue(YES);
```

Comment: Thanks, option 1 still override the data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use like this:

> Using setValue in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

You could try something like:

> ...You can still update a child without rewriting the entire object. If you want to allow users to update their profiles you could update the username as follows:

```
self.ref.child("users/(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)
```

I hope this can help you.

[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: Thanks, but `ref.child("users/(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)` 
create property called `username` and value (username value)

Comment: @Felix Have you tried with your info? like: `ref.child("players/w9pRe7sTj5aUPf3og4vUZ3kVpXs2/friends").setValue(array1)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Address on the array

```
DatabaseReference  newRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('GuessGame/numbers').push();
```

set the Data on the address.

```
 newRef.set(num);
```

**NB**: this id are autogenerated, and won't be autoincreamented